# Get connection info of Elements

Tags: javascript, html, connection, draggable, jsplumb

I'm working with jsPlumb and Javascript to implement a simple drag and drop interface of elements where connections can be made amongst each other. I would like to know how I could get the connection details of the sources and the targets when the 'setting-like' button on each dropped element is clicked.

[image: settings btn]

In the above canvas, if the settings icon of the "Empty Query" is clicked, I need to retrieve the connection info such

*in-connector:*

source id - in connector id itself & target id- "Pixar" element's connector id

*out-connector:*

source id - out connector id itself & target id- "Paramount" element's connector id

**JS Function**

```
function dropCompleteQueryElement(newAgent,i,e)
{
    $(droppedElement).draggable({containment: "container"});

    var finalElement =  newAgent;
    r++; q++;

    var connectionIn = $('<div class="connectorIn">').attr('id', i + '-in').addClass('connection').text("in");
    var connectionOut = $('<div class="connectorOut">').attr('id', i + '-out').addClass('connection').text('out');

    finalElement.css({
        'top': e.pageY,
        'left': e.pageX
    });

    finalElement.append(connectionIn);
    finalElement.append(connectionOut);

    $('#container').append(finalElement);

    jsPlumb.draggable(finalElement, {
        containment: 'parent'
    });

    jsPlumb.makeTarget(connectionIn, {
        anchor: 'Continuous'
    });

    jsPlumb.makeSource(connectionOut, {
        parent:finalElement,
        anchor: 'Continuous'
    });

    var myNode = document.getElementById("lot");
    var fc = myNode.firstChild;

    while( fc ) {
        myNode.removeChild( fc );
        fc = myNode.firstChild;
    }

}
```

newAgent is the element dragged from the  and the toolbox before the icons and labels are appended and the finalElement is the element dropped on the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understood you correctly. If you want to get information about connection, you have to call `jsPlumb.getConnections`.
To get information about in-connection you should call it with `target` specified:

```
jsPlumb.getConnections({ target:"8-in" });
```

where `8-in` is id of your target. To get information about out-connections you should call it with `source` specified:

```
jsPlumb.getConnections({ source:"8-out" });
```

where `8-out` is id of your source.

Return value is an list of connections, each connection is an object with required information `connection.sourceId`, `connection.targetId`.

See [jsPlumb help](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/querying.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out